# Store & Restore Highlighted Selection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, range

I am writing a Chrome Extention where I need to store and restore the user's highlighted selection. The stored information will be stored on my server. I am wondering how I would do this?

I looked into using Range, but am unsure if this is the right way since the example below only worked in FireFox.

I found this [example](http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/storingSelection1.html) but it only works in FireFox :(

Comment: The example works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the technique on that page probably does work in Chrome: there's no reason why it shouldn't. When I save the selection and reload, I see the selection restore and then quickly disappear, so I suspect something in the page (possibly the ads) is destroying the selection somehow.

If you can't get that to work, you could try the [serializer module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SerializerModule) of my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library, although it's probably overkill for just Chrome.

In general, using the browser's [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/selection) and [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Range) APIs is definitely the way to go. They are now standardized and universally supported (with some quirks and bugs, naturally) in current browsers.